# Does Python Re-Import File Twice?

Tags: python, import

a.py says:

```
from b import *
from c import *
```

b.py says:

```
from c import *
```

Does this cause a performance/memory hit, or does the preprocesser fix everything?  If I am too lazy to remove these in a large program will it hurt things?

Comment: "or does the preprocesser fix everything" - Python doesn't have a preprocessor. `import` isn't like a C `#include` - it doesn't just dump a bunch of text into the source code at that point. It's an imperative statement for loading resources, executed at runtime.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `import *`, though, especially for stuff you don't even need like you say you're doing. It causes all sorts of bugs where you end up referring to the wrong things, like using the wrong `open`.

Comment: "If I am too lazy to remove these in a large program will it hurt things?" mmm, I wonder why we should answer that when you won't test it or try it. Not just that but `import *` is not a good idea

Comment: @roganjosh  I mean... I guess I could build copies of a large program with and without several hundred of these and then run them inside of something measuring performance and memory usage.  Or if someone knows the answer off the top of their head they could just say.  This is something I dislike about Stack Exchange in general.  Sometimes it is better to get a human-provided answer rather than reinventing the wheel and doing extensive testing.  Although I do appreciate your comment about import *.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica  Thanks, I think that answers the question.  So it doesn't make a second copy of things or load them an extra time, right?

Comment: I disagree with the first part of the comment. More than half the things I know are from setting up borked experiments and then building my way out of them, btw

Comment: @Vincent: It will not make duplicate copies or repeat initialization for a module that has already been loaded (except for cases where you accidentally load the same file as two modules, for example if your `__main__` module is involved in a circular import).

Comment: Some modules are built expecting you to do `from a import *` - they use the `__all__` to list variables that should be imported that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python imports and caches a module once. `import` checks the cache and if the module is found, it simply binds the existing module to a local name (or binds its contents to local names as in `from foo import *`). See [The module cache](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache).